# Build jar issue but manual compilation works fine

Tags: java

I have a issue on building the jar at place.
It is not generating all .class files.

But if i manually complite the .java files i am able to generate all the .class files without any issue.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are you building the jar? Using what tools?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and imagine what readers would need to know before answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should compile the .java files before generating the jar file,
(I hope I have understand your question right)